# ASP.NET I need a counter to show up in my View for the Checkboxes which are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor, checkbox

I am looking for the following, for my Asp.Net Core Application:

[image: counter]

Just a number which is shown in the view, in a < div > or something similar, and that said number is updated, always indicating how many checkboxes I have marked in the view.

I don't know what is the usual method to show numbers in the View which are updated with an action, so I don't know how to do this, thanks in advance.

By the way, the view would have a number N of Checkboxes, with a code of the type:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div><input id=1 type="checkbox" name="group" value="Item 1" class="X"/>Item 1</div>
<div><input id=2 type="checkbox" name="group" value="Item 2" class="X"/>Item 2</div>
<div><input id=3 type="checkbox" name="group" value="Item 3" class="X"/>Item 3</div>
......
<div><input id=N type="checkbox" name="group" value="Item N" class="X"/>Item N</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$('input:checked').length`

```js
$(".X").change(function() {
    var n = $('input:checked').length;
    $("#result").text(n + ' checkboxes are checked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div><input id=1 type="checkbox" name="group" value="Item 1" class="X"/>Item 1</div>
<div><input id=2 type="checkbox" name="group" value="Item 2" class="X"/>Item 2</div>
<div><input id=3 type="checkbox" name="group" value="Item 3" class="X"/>Item 3</div>
<div><input id=N type="checkbox" name="group" value="Item N" class="X"/>Item N</div>
</div>
```